# Wordpress site server getting blocked due to resource abuse

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, plugin-recommendation, wordpress.com-hosting

I have a very weird problem going on. Namecheap always blocked my server by sayings I am overusing resource allocation.

It’s hard to figure out what plugins or files are creating problems.

I need to know the certain steps that may prevent it to have happened as it’s circling back after even 8 – 9 days in a month on average.

Any extra plugins to get the exact root cause? Any steps?

I am attaching the resource abuse log from Namecheap.

Here is the link to the database logs files Namecheap sent: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1CgcxXDcA8o8Cqm6AAM6Qh-aZUj5Q2Kqo?usp=sharing

Here is the WP Info from the health menu:

```
wp-core

version: 6.2.2
site_language: en_US
user_language: en_US
timezone: America/Toronto
permalink: /%postname%/
https_status: true
multisite: false
user_registration: 0
blog_public: 1
default_comment_status: open
environment_type: production
user_count: 16
dotorg_communication: true

wp-paths-sizes

wordpress_path: /home/primdbt/public_html
wordpress_size: 631.93 MB (662631707 bytes)
uploads_path: /home/primdbt/public_html/wp-content/uploads
uploads_size: 339.38 MB (355866159 bytes)
themes_path: /home/primdbt/public_html/wp-content/themes
themes_size: 40.58 MB (42549954 bytes)
plugins_path: /home/primdbt/public_html/wp-content/plugins
plugins_size: 298.13 MB (312607542 bytes)
database_size: 100.35 MB (105219753 bytes)
total_size: 1.38 GB (1478875115 bytes)

wp-dropins (1)

db.php: true

wp-active-theme

name: Electro Child (electro-child)
version: 2.7.2
author: MadrasThemes
author_website: https://madrasthemes.com/
parent_theme: Electro (electro)
theme_features: core-block-patterns, widgets-block-editor, post-thumbnails, automatic-feed-links, html5, custom-background, site-logo, woocommerce, wc-product-gallery-zoom, wc-product-gallery-lightbox, wc-product-gallery-slider, title-tag, post-formats, custom-logo, menus, widgets
theme_path: /home/primdbt/public_html/wp-content/themes/electro-child
auto_update: Disabled

wp-parent-theme

name: Electro (electro)
version: 2.7.2
author: MadrasThemes
author_website: https://madrasthemes.com/
theme_path: /home/primdbt/public_html/wp-content/themes/electro
auto_update: Disabled

wp-themes-inactive (5)

Twenty Nineteen: version: 2.5, author: the WordPress team, Auto-updates disabled
Twenty Twenty: version: 2.2, author: the WordPress team, Auto-updates disabled
Twenty Twenty-One: version: 1.8, author: the WordPress team, Auto-updates disabled
Twenty Twenty-Three: version: 1.1, author: the WordPress team, Auto-updates disabled
Twenty Twenty-Two: version: 1.4, author: the WordPress team, Auto-updates disabled

wp-plugins-active (38)

Advanced Shipment Tracking for WooCommerce: version: 3.5.3, author: zorem, Auto-updates disabled
AI Powered Marketing: version: 1.2.0, author: Kliken, Auto-updates disabled
Ajax add to cart for WooCommerce: version: 2.2.0, author: QuadLayers, Auto-updates disabled
Akismet Anti-Spam: Spam Protection: version: 5.2, author: Automattic - Anti Spam Team, Auto-updates disabled
Back In Stock Notifier for WooCommerce | WooCommerce Waitlist Pro: version: 4.0.0, author: codewoogeek, Auto-updates disabled
ChitChats Shipping for WooCommerce: version: 1.5.10, author: OneTeamSoftware, Auto-updates enabled
Cookie Notice & Compliance for GDPR / CCPA: version: 2.4.9, author: Hu-manity.co, Auto-updates disabled
Electro Extensions: version: 2.7.2, author: MadrasThemes, Auto-updates disabled
Extendify: version: 1.7.0, author: Extendify, Auto-updates disabled
Facebook for WooCommerce: version: 3.0.26, author: Facebook, Auto-updates disabled
Health Check & Troubleshooting: version: 1.6.0, author: The WordPress.org community, Auto-updates enabled
Jetpack: version: 12.2.1, author: Automattic, Auto-updates enabled
Jetpack Boost: version: 1.9.1, author: Automattic - Jetpack Site Speed team, Auto-updates enabled
Jetpack Protect: version: 1.4.0, author: Automattic - Jetpack Security team, Auto-updates disabled
Mailchimp for WooCommerce: version: 2.8.3, author: Mailchimp, Auto-updates disabled
MC4WP: Mailchimp for WordPress: version: 4.9.5, author: ibericode, Auto-updates disabled
Meta pixel for WordPress: version: 3.0.12, author: Facebook, Auto-updates disabled
Modal Window: version: 5.3.5, author: Wow-Company, Auto-updates disabled
Query Monitor: version: 3.12.3, author: John Blackbourn, Auto-updates disabled
Rank Math SEO: version: 1.0.118, author: Rank Math, Auto-updates disabled
Redux Framework: version: 4.4.3, author: Team Redux (latest version: 4.4.4), Auto-updates disabled
Simple Custom CSS and JS: version: 3.44, author: SilkyPress.com, Auto-updates disabled
Site Kit by Google: version: 1.103.0, author: Google, Auto-updates disabled
Slider Revolution: version: 6.3.8, author: ThemePunch, Auto-updates disabled
SVG Flags: version: 0.9.6, author: David Gwyer, Auto-updates disabled
UpdraftPlus - Backup/Restore: version: 1.23.6, author: UpdraftPlus.Com, DavidAnderson, Auto-updates disabled
Variation Swatches for WooCommerce: version: 2.0.23, author: Emran Ahmed, Auto-updates disabled
WooCommerce: version: 7.8.1, author: Automattic, Auto-updates disabled
WooCommerce Checkout Manager: version: 7.1.7, author: QuadLayers, Auto-updates disabled
Woocommerce eShipper Shipping Calculator: version: 3.0.2, author: Eshippers, Auto-updates disabled
WooCommerce PayPal Payments: version: 2.1.0, author: WooCommerce, Auto-updates disabled
WooCommerce Shipping & Tax: version: 2.2.5, author: WooCommerce, Auto-updates disabled
WooCommerce Shipping Estimates: version: 2.4.0, author: SkyVerge, Auto-updates disabled
WPBakery Page Builder: version: 6.0.5, author: Michael M - WPBakery.com (latest version: 6.13.0), Auto-updates disabled
WPForms Lite: version: 1.8.2.2, author: WPForms, Auto-updates disabled
WP Mail Logging: version: 1.12.0, author: WP Mail Logging Team, Auto-updates disabled
YITH WooCommerce Compare: version: 2.27.0, author: YITH, Auto-updates disabled
YITH WooCommerce Wishlist: version: 3.22.0, author: YITH, Auto-updates disabled

wp-plugins-inactive (6)

Font Awesome: version: 4.3.2, author: Font Awesome, Auto-updates disabled
MAS Brands for WooCommerce: version: 1.0.6, author: MadrasThemes, Auto-updates disabled
MAS Static Content: version: 1.0.5, author: MadrasThemes, Auto-updates disabled
One Click Demo Import: version: 3.1.2, author: OCDI, Auto-updates disabled
WooCommerce PayPal Checkout Gateway: version: 2.1.3, author: WooCommerce, Auto-updates disabled
WooCommerce Price Based on Country: version: 3.2.0, author: Oscar Gare, Auto-updates disabled

wp-media

image_editor: WP_Image_Editor_GD
imagick_module_version: Not available
imagemagick_version: Not available
imagick_version: Not available
file_uploads: File uploads is turned off
post_max_size: 1024M
upload_max_filesize: 1024M
max_effective_size: 1 GB
max_file_uploads: 20
gd_version: 2.3.3
gd_formats: GIF, JPEG, PNG, WebP, BMP, XPM
ghostscript_version: 8.70

wp-server

server_architecture: Linux 2.6.32-954.3.5.lve1.4.90.el6.x86_64 x86_64
httpd_software: LiteSpeed
php_version: 7.4.33 64bit
php_sapi: litespeed
max_input_variables: 2000
time_limit: 1500
memory_limit: 1024M
max_input_time: 1500
upload_max_filesize: 1024M
php_post_max_size: 1024M
curl_version: 7.87.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1p
suhosin: false
imagick_availability: false
pretty_permalinks: true
htaccess_extra_rules: true

wp-database

extension: mysqli
server_version: 10.5.21-MariaDB-cll-lve-log
client_version: mysqlnd 7.4.33
max_allowed_packet: 524288000
max_connections: 500

wp-constants

WP_HOME: undefined
WP_SITEURL: undefined
WP_CONTENT_DIR: /home/primdbt/public_html/wp-content
WP_PLUGIN_DIR: /home/primdbt/public_html/wp-content/plugins
WP_MEMORY_LIMIT: 40M
WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT: 1024M
WP_DEBUG: false
WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY: true
WP_DEBUG_LOG: false
SCRIPT_DEBUG: false
WP_CACHE: true
CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS: undefined
COMPRESS_SCRIPTS: undefined
COMPRESS_CSS: undefined
WP_ENVIRONMENT_TYPE: Undefined
DB_CHARSET: utf8mb4
DB_COLLATE: undefined

wp-filesystem

wordpress: writable
wp-content: writable
uploads: writable
plugins: writable
themes: writable
0: Writable

redux-framework

version: 4.4.3
installation: plugin
data directory: /home/primdbt/public_html/wp-content/plugins/redux-framework/redux-core/
browser:
Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Browser: Chrome
Version: 114.0.0.0
Platform: Apple

redux-instance-electro_options

opt_name: electro_options
global_variable: electro_options
dev_mode: false
ajax_save: true
page_slug: theme_options
page_permissions: manage_options
menu_type: menu
page_parent: themes.php
compiler: true
output: true
output_tag: true
templates_path: undefined
extensions:
Accordion: 4.3.16
Custom Fonts: 4.4.2
Customizer: 4.4.2
Datetime: 4.3.15
Google Maps: 4.4.0
Icon Select: 4.4.2
Import Export: 4.0.0
Js Button: 4.3.16
Metaboxes: 4.2.0
Multi Media: 4.4.1
Options Object: 4.0.0
Repeater: 4.3.13
Search: 3.4.5
Shortcodes: 4.3.6
Social Profiles: 4.3.17
Users: 4.4.1
Widget Areas: 4.3.20

jetpack

site_id: 188928073
ssl_cert: No
time_diff: undefined
version_option: 12.2.1:1687783449
old_version: 11.8.4:1687748573
public: Public
master_user: #1 admin
is_offline_mode: off
is_offline_mode_constant: off
current_user: #1 admin
tokens_set: Blog User
blog_token: *0v)Y($tz!k!V6A)#C4Wi$ow9XoctURU
user_token: o!pTKUk2sGHlaNpE4Sndw2WFEwGj1P^^
version: 12.2.1
jp_plugin_dir: /home/primdbt/public_html/wp-content/plugins/jetpack/
plan: free
protect_header: {"trusted_header":"REMOTE_ADDR","segments":1,"reverse":false}
full_sync: {"started":"Thu, 29 Jun 2023 03:16:09 +0000","finished":"Thu, 29 Jun 2023 03:20:01 +0000","progress":{"comments":{"total":"113","sent":113,"finished":true,"last_sent":"118"},"constants":{"finished":true},"functions":{"finished":true},"options":{"finished":true},"posts":{"total":"1685","sent":1685,"finished":true,"last_sent":"2"},"term_relationships":{"total":"913","sent":913,"finished":true,"last_sent":{"object_id":"2932","term_taxonomy_id":"2"}},"terms":{"total":"221","sent":221,"finished":true,"last_sent":"1"},"themes":{"finished":true},"updates":{"finished":true},"users":{"total":"1","sent":1,"finished":true,"last_sent":"1"}},"config":{"comments":1,"constants":1,"functions":1,"options":1,"posts":1,"term_relationships":1,"terms":1,"themes":1,"updates":1,"users":1}}
sync_size: undefined
sync_lag: 0 seconds
full_sync_size: undefined
full_sync_lag: 0 seconds
idc_urls: {"home":"https:\/\/www.prime4buy.ca","siteurl":"https:\/\/www.prime4buy.ca","WP_HOME":"","WP_SITEURL":""}
idc_error_option: false
idc_optin: true
cxn_tests: All Pass.

google-site-kit

version: 1.103.0
php_version: 7.4.33
wp_version: 6.2.2
reference_url: https://www.prime4buy.ca
amp_mode: no
site_status: not-connected
user_status: not authenticated
verification_status: verified-non-site-kit
connected_user_count: 1
active_modules: site-verification, search-console, adsense, analytics, analytics-4, pagespeed-insights, tagmanager
recoverable_modules: none
required_scopes:
openid: ✅
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile: ✅
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email: ✅
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/siteverification: ✅
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters: ✅
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adsense.readonly: ✅
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly: ✅
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tagmanager.readonly: ✅
capabilities:
googlesitekit_authenticate: ✅
googlesitekit_setup: ✅
googlesitekit_view_posts_insights: ⭕
googlesitekit_view_dashboard: ⭕
googlesitekit_manage_options: ⭕
googlesitekit_update_plugins: ⭕
googlesitekit_view_splash: ✅
googlesitekit_view_authenticated_dashboard: ⭕
googlesitekit_view_wp_dashboard_widget: ⭕
googlesitekit_view_admin_bar_menu: ⭕
googlesitekit_view_shared_dashboard: ⭕
googlesitekit_read_shared_module_data::["search-console"]: ⭕
googlesitekit_read_shared_module_data::["analytics"]: ⭕
googlesitekit_read_shared_module_data::["pagespeed-insights"]: ⭕
googlesitekit_manage_module_sharing_options::["search-console"]: ⭕
googlesitekit_manage_module_sharing_options::["analytics"]: ⭕
googlesitekit_manage_module_sharing_options::["pagespeed-insights"]: ⭕
googlesitekit_delegate_module_sharing_management::["search-console"]: ⭕
googlesitekit_delegate_module_sharing_management::["analytics"]: ⭕
googlesitekit_delegate_module_sharing_management::["pagespeed-insights"]: ⭕
enabled_features:
adBlockerDetection: ⭕
adsenseSetupV2: ✅
dashboardSharing: ✅
ga4ActivationBanner: ✅
ga4Reporting: ⭕
gm3Components: ⭕
gteSupport: ⭕
userInput: ⭕
search-console_shared_roles: none
search-console_management: owner
analytics_shared_roles: none
analytics_management: owner
pagespeed-insights_shared_roles: none
pagespeed-insights_management: all_admins
search_console_property: https://www.prime4buy.ca/
adsense_account_id: pub-443•••••••••••••
adsense_client_id: ca-pub-443•••••••••••••
adsense_account_status: pending
adsense_site_status: none
adsense_use_snippet: yes
adsense_web_stories_adunit_id: none
analytics_account_id: 1985•••••
analytics_property_id: UA-1985•••••••
analytics_profile_id: 2441•••••
analytics_use_snippet: yes
analytics_4_property_id: none
analytics_4_web_data_stream_id: none
analytics_4_measurement_id: none
analytics_4_use_snippet: yes
tagmanager_account_id: 6004••••••
tagmanager_container_id: GTM-KR4••••
tagmanager_amp_container_id: none
tagmanager_use_snippet: yes

wpforms

version: 1.8.2.2
lite: Feb 2, 2021 @ 9:16pm
pro: Feb 21, 2021 @ 9:06am
upload_dir: Writable
total_forms: 2
total_submissions: 1889
```

Can some expert please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if anyone can provide a complete answer without digging in to your specifics but the following may be helpful -

Looking at the database log file sent by Namecheap they appear to be objecting to the amount of CPU you are using

The first thing I would look at doing is installing some kind of cache like W3 Total Cache.  Caching will greatly decrease the amount of CPU and also speed up your site.

The second thing I would do is try and remove/consolidate plugins - It looks very much to me like this is a "death by a 1000 paper cuts" scenario - 38 Plugins is an awful lot - and each plugin is using CPU (and generally making your site less secure and harder to maintain)

It may also be that you simply need to buy bigger/better hosting (you have not mentioned your site, or the volume of hits so we can't know for sure)

Comment: Another couple of things to consider - Its probably a big ask but if your provider supports PHP 8.1 / 8.2  it may be worth trying to upgrade (not without its difficulties - especially with that number of plugins) but PHP 8 .1 / 8.2  is substantially faster = less CPU - then PHP 7.4.  (Figures vary dramatically depending on workload, but 5% at the low and and 30%+ in many use cases)

Comment: I have installed the Caching plugin now provided by Namecheap. Yes, I removed a couple of plugins now. Most of them are not activated from 38 plugins. Also, I am not sure about the next hosting. Website hits are very low in number. We usually do not get new order very frequently. Also upgraded to PHP 8.1 from cpanel.

Comment: Does your site load noticeably faster now? (cpu utilizatio is inversely corrlelated to site speed)? Its worth considering removing unused plugins from a security POV.

Comment: They say still the values are bit abnormal and they want to fix it to 0 tolerance :D. Anyways, I am hoping it will be better. Otherwise I will move to new host. Here is the website, if you want to test it? Link: https://www.prime4buy.ca/

Comment: I cant properly test it right now, but I did browse it from my cellphone. You might want to clean up your text pages as there are exposed tags relating to wp-bakery/visual composer.  Some questions - what caching plugin did Namecheap provide? What account plan do you have? Have Namecheap been specific about the resources they are concerned about?

Comment: Yes, I disabled wp-bakery so they popped up. I will remove it. They provide "LiteSpeed Web Cache Manager". I am using the Stellar Plus (https://www.namecheap.com/hosting/shared/) hosting plan. They just say you are doing resource abuse and queries are getting fired on db so you need to control CPU etc.

Comment: I'm not an expert on Lightspeed Cache but I do wonder if its tailored more for the front-end side of things between the web server and wordpress, rather then handling Wordpress.   It might be worth trying to disabling Lightspeed Cache and then installing and configuring W3 Total Cache which I suspect will be a lot better in caching objects in the Wordpress backend.

Comment: You may want to perform some Lighthouse checks on your site and follow its recommendations.  Your performance is < 50/100 desktop, < 50/100 for desktop ).  While fixing these issues won't directly solve your problem - implementing the fixes will likely have the side effect of making you redo things in a way which will reduce your resource utilization (and get you more business) - for example it shows your caching is not doing its job very well right now.  You can see Lighthouse in Chrome by cicking on the 3 vertical dots at the top right, then "More Tools" -> "Developer Tools" -> "Lighthouse"

Comment: Thanks so much I have followed your suggestion and working on the rest. I am accepting your answer for now. :) I will post if I need to know anything. :)